# Do the native video recording apps on Android and the iPhone include geolocation data when you upload to YouTube?

Tags: iphone, android, youtube

Do the native video recording apps on Android and the iPhone embed geolocation data when you choose the "upload to YouTube" option? In other words, does the youtube upload contain the location coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded a video with iOS 4.1 from my iPhone 4 a few months ago to youtube (it was an HD version).  I went into my account and I can verify that as of 4.1 geolocation information was not included.  I will upload a test video from iOS 4.2.1 and report back the results.

Comment: I can confirm a video uploaded to youtube via the 'Photos' app in iOS 4.2.1 does NOT include geolocation information.

Comment: Thank you very much, clonked. I appreciate your help immensely. May I ask how it is that you're judging whether or not geolocation information is included? I don't know if the gelocation information is actually publicly viewable on YouTube. It's possible that the only way to tell whether it was included is via the YouTube geo-search API: You search for videos within the location that you uploaded your video from and see whether it shows up. Or, you can probably just read its location via the API.

Comment: What I did was login to my account, and then went to the 'My Videos' section of my account.  In there I clicked the 'Edit' button for the video I uploaded from my phone.  On that page is a 'Date and Map' section that allows me to provide geolocation coordinates.  They are not set so it is my assumption that this information was not uploaded with the video.